# Range.AdvancedFilter yielding inconsistent results

Tags: excel, vba

Using VBA, I am trying to create an array of individual worksheets based on the unique values in a column of data.

Although I am using the same data, the number of elements created will vary between 263 (incorrect) and 268 (correct).

These unique records are pulled from a master list containing 7667 records (with duplicates).

The issue appears to be in the Range.AdvancedFilter portion of my script. This will usually copy over the correct number of unique records, but, rarely, it will be incorrect.

It has returned both of these results, regardless of any changes made to the script. I haven't figured out how to replicate this error.

When the error occurs, it looks like the bottom five unique records from the master list are missing from the filtered list. This appears to be consistent between errors.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim aArray() As Variant
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim aRange As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Worksheets.Add After:=Sheets(1)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Temporary_1"
    Sheets(1).Activate
    Sheets(1).Range(Range("D1"), Range("D1").End(xlDown)).AdvancedFilter 
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets(2).Range("A1"), Unique:=True
    Sheets(2).Activate

    Set aRange = Sheets(2).Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    Debug.Print aRange.Count
    ReDim aArray(aRange.Count - 1)
    For Each cell In aRange.Cells
        aArray(x) = cell.Value
        x = x + 1
    Next cell

    i = 0
    For x = LBound(aArray) To UBound(aArray)
        i = i + 1
    Next x
    Debug.Print i

End Sub
```

Is there a more reliable way to create an array from the unique records within a column?

Comment: Where do you `Set PlanNameRange`? Or is that just a typo that you have `Set aRange` right before using `PlanNameRange`?

Comment: I'm surprised it's letting you copy to another worksheet.  It looks like you've got `Sheets(1)` yet you are copying to `Sheets(2)`.  What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @BigBen 

You are correct, It was a typo from copying the script over and then changing variable names. I've fixed the typos in the post.

Comment: Perhaps there is some subtle difference in the data that is causing it to return more uniques.  Non-printing character; trailing space.  I suggest you look carefully at the apparent discrepancy items.

Comment: @Cyril Shouldn't the `Unique` parameter of the method accomplish that?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld It should accomplish that.  My suggestion would be preference, as maintaining and checking keys in the immediate window is a bit easier (imo).  If the issue is with an incorrect number of unique records, or possibly not using the correct range (`Range("D1").End(xlDown)` stops on blank), it may be a more ideal approach to use the specific values between `cells(1,4)` and `cells(rows.count,4).end(xlup).row`.  Similarly, it might be as simple as using `cells(1,4)` and `cells(rows.count,4).end(xlup).row` over the xldown in the related line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `.End(xlDown)`, though we don't know if there is a blank space in your data.

Have you tried changed

```
Sheets(1).Range(Range("D1"), Range("D1").End(xlDown)).AdvancedFilter
```

to read:

```
With Sheets(1)
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(.Range("D1"), .Range("D" & lr)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets(2).Range("A1"), Unique:=True
End With
```

Notice that I also added the Sheet references to the other range, since that would appropriately qualify the range (the first sheets(1) IS NOT carried through or assumed by VBA).

Comment: Thanks, this will be useful for parsing past any blanks in a column. 

I've updated my script accordingly. 

Unfortunately, there were no blanks in the data that I was using. So I still don't know what was causing the error.

Comment: @AntonParoski Please also note the final statement in the answer about qualifying *all* ranges.